# I want to put django's object in the templapates JavaScript, but I can't What should I do?

Tags: javascript, django

```
class KcalDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'target_kcal'
    template_name = 'kcalculatorapp/detail.html'
  
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kcl = self.request.user.kcal
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        i = 0
        kcal_list = []
        while i < 13:
            i = i + 1;
            if kcl.goal == 'diet':
                kcal_list.append((kcl.weight -round((500/7000)*i,2) ))
            else:
                kcal_list.append((kcl.weight + round((500 / 7000) * i,2)))

        context['kcal_list'] = kcal_list

        return context
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels

this chart use.

`templates.html`

```
    .
    .
    .
<script>
    .
    .
    .
        series: [{
            name: 'a',
            data: {{  kcal_list }}     // this !!!
        }]
    });
</script>
```

For example
kcal_list = [ 10, 13, 15, 16, 20 ]
It's in the form of a list.

And data: [10, 13, 15, 16, 20] Why does it look like this?

data : {{kcal_list}} is not possible?

What should I do?

Comment: What is the actual output of the template when you look at the source in the browser? press Ctrl+U

Comment: Type html, script, each {{kcal_list}}
If you press ctrl + u,

html file
[60, 62, 63, 66, 68~~~~~] It comes out like this.

I can't see it in the scripts at all.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. `data: [10, 13, 15, 16, 20]` is valid JS, at least as part of an object. However I wouldn't use a template at all but request JSON from django. Use https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.columnsURL and provide a django endpoint that servers the data as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The {{variable}} is substituted directly into the HTML. Do a view source; it isn't a "variable" or anything like it. It's just rendered text.

Having said that, you can put this kind of substitution into your JavaScript.

```
 <script>
        
                series: [{
                    name: 'a',
                    data: "{{  kcal_list }}"     // this !!!
                }]
            });
        </script>
```